# How can i type some possible states of a class instance?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript.
I have a vector class and a type that only accepts 4 possible states of the vector.

```
class Vector{
  x:number = 0;
  y:number = 0;

  constructor(x:number, y:number){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

type DirectionVector = 
  {
    x: 1;
    y: 0;
  } | {
    x: -1;
    y: 0;
  } | {
    x: 0;
    y: 1;
  } | {
    x: 0; 
    y: -1;
  }
```

I want to be able to type some of my vectors so that they can only be from one of those 4 states

this is what i expected

```
const vec:DirectionVector = new Vector(5,3); //type error
const vec2:DirectionVector = new Vector(1,0); //good
```

and this is what i get

```
const vec2:DirectionVector = new Vector(1,0);
/*
Type 'Vector' is not assignable to type 'DirectionVector'.
  Type 'Vector' is not assignable to type '{ x: 0; y: -1; }'.
    Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'
*/
```

Comment: If you want the compiler to keep track of the particular literal numeric values a `Vector` has for `x` and `y`, you need to make `Vector` *generic* in their types, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP9X5w).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for, thank you very much, an explanation would be very good please.

Comment: Oh well, I see there's another answer here that recommends the same approach.  I suppose I won't write up one then.  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want one number to be zero and you have not extended the class. Now, from the below code it will work as X extends number in a generic type definition assumes that X should include all properties from number, but X might have others also and the same goes for Y type.

```
class Vector<X extends number, Y extends number>{
  x: X;
  y: Y;

  constructor(x: X, y: Y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

type DirectionVector =
  {
    x: 1;
    y: 0;
  } | {
    x: -1;
    y: 0;
  } | {
    x: 0;
    y: 1;
  } | {
    x: 0;
    y: -1;
  }

const vec: DirectionVector = new Vector(5, 3); //type error
const vec2: DirectionVector = new Vector(1, 0); //good
```

Expected error:

```
Type 'Vector<5, 3>' is not assignable to type 'DirectionVector'.
  Type 'Vector<5, 3>' is not assignable to type '{ x: 0; y: -1; }'.
    Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
      Type '5' is not assignable to type '0'.
```